# connectionDidFinishLoading is notified before my service is finished

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have data returned from a service that is rendered to my UITableView several times.  I moved placed the code that populates my table in the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate.  Is this the correct placement of that code?

I have a NSMutableData* receivedData; at the top of my .m file and I have implemented the correct delegates and overridden the correct methods.

I just want to know what I am missing here or what I can do to only see the data from my JSON once in the table view.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {    
[receivedData setLength:0];
NSLog(@"%@",response);}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[data length]);
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[receivedData appendData:data];}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSError *error = nil;
// Get the JSON data from the website
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    for (NSArray *item in result) {
        NSArray *category = [item valueForKey:@"CategoryName"];
        [dataArray addObject:category];
    }
}
else {
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

    for(NSDictionary *item in jsonDictionary)
        NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
}

[self.tableView reloadData];

NSLog(@"Finished");}
```

Comment: Can you show the @interface section where receivedData is declared?

Comment: And, can you be more specific about what isn't happening, or a specific error you are seeing.

Comment: 1) As a side issue didReceiveData: will probably get called several times so you should not be allocating receivedData in it each time. 2) As for the rest your question is confused and contradictory - the title says connectionDidFinishLoading is notified before the service finished, implying you didn't get all the data, yet in your description you say "to only see the data once", implying you are getting it more times then you expected. If you're confused, so are we by this description. 3)doing something with the data in connectionDidFinishLoading is the correct place

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the response.  The didRecieveData is implemented in the code above at the top of the code listing.  This is in my .m file.  The reason I feel the connectionDidFinishLoading is called before ALL the data is received is because that is where I am actually iterating over the data that I have placed in the NSMutableArray I have called receivedData and I am seeing my array, which has 9 items in it, about 6 times on average.  So my UITableView has about 45 total records.  I am getting all my data that I expect but I am seeing that didReceiveData is triggered multiple times.

Comment: If I place a break point on connectionDidFinishLoading and run the application I can see that method being called again and again.  That's when I see my table view appended to with a new set of nine values.  These are the nine values I expect to receive from my WebAPI call.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening?  No matter where I put the code, didReceiveData or connectionDidFinishLoading, I still get my table view populated over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a line with an error

```
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

Every time you receive the data you are initializing your object again.

I do recommend this page http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/6-afnetworking for your JSON part.